# Trying to convert register memory macro into a function

Tags: c++

I know `#define REG(x) (*((volatile unsigned int *)(x)))` is simply a macro for retrieving the values stored in a register but what does its equivalent function look like?

I'm trying to create a function similar to

```
unsigned int readAddr(int x)
{
    volatile unsigned int output = *(volatile unsigned int *)(x);
    cout << output << endl;
    return *(volatile unsigned int *)(x);
}
```

But I get errors about casting the pointer from an integer of a different size. As you can see, my understanding of pointers, CBR, and CBV is quite rusty.

Comment: The reason you're getting this warning is that `volatile unsigned int *` and `int` are different sizes on your computer architecture.

Comment: You probably need to declare it `long x` instead of `int x`.